# Is possible to publish a Nuxt app as package on NPM to be reused in another Nuxt App? If yes, how would I do this?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have two Nuxt applications, the app1 is a module and a would like to keep it in a separate repository. I will build the app1 and publish it in the NPM package, in app2 I will install the package from npm registry. How can I import `dist/` folder of app1 to app2 mapping the router or creating a vue component that opens `index.html` inside `node_modules/app1/dist/index.html`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a nuxt module and either use it directly or publish it to npm. Refer to this link in the nuxt documentation for more information:

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/modules#write-your-own-module

You can also refer to this medium article that has more detailed steps (I have to try this out):

https://medium.com/carepenny/creating-a-nuxt-module-1c6e3cdf1037